# Can't assign value to a global variable when passed from onClick()

Tags: java, android

I am trying to pass a data to a variable form inside onClick. 
 it returns null. I will then use that variable to pass it into a method. I am relatively new to android programming and this has been bugging me for hours. here is my code:

MainActivity.java

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 ConnectionClass connectionClass;
 EditText edtuserid,edtpass;
 Button btnlogin;
 ProgressBar pbbar;

 public String name = "";
 String userid;
 String password;

 Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 connectionClass = new ConnectionClass();
 edtuserid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtuserid);
 edtpass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtpass);
 btnlogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnlogin);
 pbbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pbbar);
 pbbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);


btnlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
     userid = edtuserid.getText().toString();
     password = edtpass.getText().toString();

     name = userid;


 }
 });
 }

 }

public String getMyData() {

    String test4 = name;
    return test4;

 }
}
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific?  you are trying to set an instance variable to null and that doesn't work?

Comment: where you have declared **test3** variable?? in the code you have posted.

Comment: You have not declared `test3` variable...replace your `test` variable to `test3`..that will work

Comment: I am trying to set test3 as the value of the edit text. I then call test3 then assign it to test4 inside my getMyData method.

Comment: and why dont just asign whatever value you want directly to your variable test?

Comment: Change the line `test3 = userid;` to `test = userid;` and in `getMyData()` method also the line `String test4 = test3;` to `String test4 = test;`

Comment: I have tried it, but it still does not work. when I assign an integer to the name variable it works, but when I just assign it, it returns null

Comment: Not getting what you wanna asked. Where your getting null?? when you calling `getMyData()`???

Comment: I am calling     getMyData() inside a fragment. when the fragment starts, I display it using toast and it displays null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using shared preferences...

```
btnlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
 userid = edtuserid.getText().toString();
 password = edtpass.getText().toString();

SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE); 
Editor editor = pref.edit();
editor.putString("name_from_main", userid );  // Saving string

// Save the changes in SharedPreferences
editor.commit(); // commit changes


}
});
```

//In your fragment use this

```
 SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE); 
 Editor editor = pref.edit();
String name_from_main = pref.getString("name_from_main", null);
```

Comment: will I put this in the onCreateView method of the fragment?

Comment: U use it in onCreate 
My suggestion is to create a global variable name_from_main ,

Assign on onCreate
Then try it will work.. 
If it doesnt I have another work around

Comment: OH MY GOD. THANKS. I HAVE BEEN DOING THIS SINCE YESTERDAY!. I AM IN DEBT. =))))